# After typing # browser all data is getting distroyed but ASCII value of # which is "%23" output is printing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ascii

I'm working in react three.js. i created one dashboard page in which i'm creating name. but whenever i'm typing # in front of name it is not redirecting on next page.

```
  if (e.target.value.match(/[!@$%^&*()\=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/+?]/)) {
  alert("Special characters not allowed");
  this.setState({
    item: ""
  });
}
```